# Copy data from a container to a host after script execution using entry point

Tags: docker

I have a DockerFile which is executing script inside, and its taking credentials as input.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as build-stage
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "create-env-list.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "./create-env-list.sh" ]
```

I am passing the credentials after the image is build and I am running it. E.g.

```
docker run --rm -it image-name:latest arg1 arg2
```

The script generates a file inside the container. I want to copy it to the host after the execution, but the container is stopped after the process is done, like it should be. I cannot use docker cp in that case to get the file.

I have read a lot of articles and docs. I achieve this with multi-stage build, but then I must pass the args for the script inside the DockerFile which I don't want to do.

Comment: You can use volumes, in which case the file will stay there. More info here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `--rm` from the run command. The container will then stay available in the exited state.

`--rm` means to remove the container when it finishes.

Comment: The container is still not there after docker container ps command

Comment: use `docker ps -a`

Comment: And they are with status exited, I tough I need a running container to use a cp command ? My bad I see I can use cp command from an exited ( non-running container ). Thank you a lot :)